# How to declare a variable which holds Timestamp value from database?

Tags: java, timestamp

I have a timestamp in my database. I want to fetch it from database using JAVA and display it to the user. How do I declare timestamp in JAVA? I am using Date, but it is storing yyyy-mm-ddd format. I want yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

```
    Date date = siteBean.getAlertTime();
```

I want the date variable to hold yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider working with Calendar, as [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is deprecated. The JavaDocs explains nicely how to replace your code with Calendar-methods.

Comment: `Date` is not deprecated, most of its methods are

Answer (score 0):

Consider fetching the timestamp from your ResultSet as a String. You can manipulate the String within Java with the help of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).